# How can I hide the PDO errors in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

I tried use with @ operator. I need hide errors because I controlling connect status with true or false value.
If give an error I can't check with true or false.
I tried "@new PDO"

Comment: Can you please add the code you have and explain the issue?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean with "give an error"?

PDO throws an exception if the requested database fails.

You can use a try/catch-Block to catch this exceptions.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```